# How to add a parameter to a URL using .htaccess without breaking WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-get

I need to add a parameter to a URL without breaking the WordPress funtionality.

I've solved the part of adding the parameter with the help of many posts here.

First I couldn't login when I added the parameter, but that is why I added the RewriteCond with the REQUEST_URI.

But now I can't publish pages on my WordPress site.
When I am logged in into the back-end of WordPress, and add a new page and publish it, it should not not discard the changes and 're-publish' the current version, nor should it give a publish/update failure message.
Currently it looks like it simply reverts to the current version, but the message that the page is successfully published appears. Or it gives an error, depending on which RewriteCond / REQUEST_URI line use.

This is what I now have in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/wp-login.*|/wp-admin)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!key)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $0?key=value[QSA,L,NC,NE,R]
```

I also tried to change

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/wp-login.*|/wp-admin)`

to

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^wp-*`

but then I get an error that updating the page failed. When adding a new page, but I get a 'Publish failed' message.

Each URL should have ?key=value appended, except for URLs with wp-login.php or wp-admin without breaking the other functionality of the WordPress Back-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this myself after more digging.

I added 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(/wp-login.*|/wp-admin)`

and now the key-value pair is not blocking WordPress from saving posts and pages.